# Aptana tab indentation guides

Tags: eclipse, indentation, aptana

I recently moved from geany to Aptana as I'm working on some bigger projects and felt I would benefit from a full IDE.

One feature I'm really missing is the little grey line every four spaces to help me maintain indentation consistency. Does anything like this exist for Aptana/Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

get the PDT tools Indent Guide plugin

Comment: Instead of just naming the tool you could have provided [a link](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/downloads/) to the plugin directly or a link on a [how to](http://aptanaandpdt.blogspot.co.at/) that explains the installation process

Answer (score 0):

Under 
*Preferences -> General -> Editor -> Texteditor* you can activate *"Show whitespace characters"*. If you click on "whitespace characters", you can define, which character should be displayed. Here you can active "Tabs". It's not as good as the lines from Notepad++, but better than nothing.

Answer (score -1):

You can set a print margin indicator (vertical line) in Preferences > General > Editors > Text Editors - but this would only be a single line. You could use tabs instead of spaces - there are options to insert spaces when you use the Tab key. In this same menu, you can choose to show whitespace characters, which will help keep your spacing in order. I don't know of any grid options.